# server-client-server-client-server-... Let's avoid infinite recursions

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

[server-client](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server-client) has a wiki and 63 questions, [client-server](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-server) has no wiki and 21 questions. I think that there is no real difference between them and one should be merged into the other (probably the latter into the first).

Comment: I'd tend to suggest the *other* way around. client-server is a ***much*** more common term. ([google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=client-server%2Cserver-client&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cclient%20-%20server%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bclient%20-%20server%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BClient%20-%20Server%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BClient%20-%20server%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cserver%20-%20client%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bserver%20-%20client%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BServer%20-%20Client%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BServer%20-%20client%3B%2Cc0))

Comment: @MichaelT That's actually how I found out about this. When tagging my question I typed "client-server" and was surprised to see that "server-client" was prevalent and with a wiki. My suggestion in the question is purely based on the consensus in this site. I would do it the other way around, personally.

Comment: It's called divergence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

I kept [client-server](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-server) as the master tag, since it's the [more common term](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7788/server-client-server-client-server-lets-avoid-infinite-recursions#comment23609_7788). Also, Stack Overflow has the [same mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/client-server/synonyms).

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.